# Capitalizing the first letter of a string using ascii table

Tags: arrays, string, ascii

How can I capitalize only the first letter of an array of strings by using the ascii table ?

for instance say I have the sentence

> " i am going to the beach", "my name is tom", "hello everyone"

.
I want to make it into

> "I am going to the beach", My name is tom", Hello everyone"

.
I thought of doing it like writing a loop of for and then another for that will run over the string in each cell in the array,and writing an if command that will say " if the letter is between 'a'-'z', go 32 letters backwards(By the ASCII table). But I didn't know how to write it.

In addition, I need to return the number of fixes that were made. 
for example, if i had the sentences from above, it will return "fix 3 capital letters".

Thank you!

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Can you also post some code showing your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: Yes!  I am using java language. I started writing this code :              for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++){
   String sentence=text[i];
   for(int j=0;j<sentence.length();j++){
    if(sentence.charAt(0)))

Comment: Please add the code to your question. :-)

Comment: Is it required that you use the ASCII table? There is really no need to do that, since Java already provides you with that functionality.

Comment: And, Java strings don't use ASCII, they use Unicode/UTF-16. Unicode includes all of the ASCII characters so you could write an algorithm that only works with those characters. But why would you do that when standard Java classes like `Character` handle casing manipulations for all 120,000 or so letters?

Answer (score 0):

Using an **ASCII** table is completely unnecessary, you just need to check **if char at index 0 is lowercase or not**, if so increase a counter and change the string.

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    String array[] = { "i am going to the beach", "my name is tom", "hello everyone" };
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        char initChar = array[j].charAt(0);
        if (Character.isLowerCase(initChar)) {
            counter++;
            array[j] = Character.toUpperCase(initChar) + array[j].substring(1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("We have refactor " + counter + " sentences");
}
```